# What is the point of batch processing nowadays?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink

I come from a batch processing background, but recently started working exclusively with streaming. I found out that in apache Spark structured streaming, for example, we can do `Trigger.AvailableNow()` and it will process all available data and stop, when there's no more data, and its advantages over batch are:

1. The fact that it checkpoints, so you won't get into a situation, like in batch, where you waited for a job to run for 5 out of 6 hours and it failed, and now you have to restart it again and wait another 6 hours. You can simply restart from checkpoint and continue where you left off.
2. `Trigger.AvailableNow()` also breaks input data into microbatches, so, I guess there's a much smaller chance that `OutOfMemoryException` will occur. Am I right?

So, with all this in mind, I'd like someone more experienced to explain to me what is the point of batch processing? Can't we do everything with streaming with more advantages?

I guess I don't know certain technical details.

Maybe there's less support for connectors to different sources with streaming, but can't that be easily resolved?

Comment: batch is more efficient. checkpointing is expensive. it doesn't have to be 5-6 hours batches, though.

Comment: Why is checkpointing expensive? If you do it like every half a second, maybe.

Comment: you have to write that state somewhere. it doesn't have to take a lot of resources, but it's not free. When you reach the capacity of a system, it counts.

Comment: Checkpointing is not a trivial task. As an example, an AWS Kinesis Flink application running with parallelism of 12 (with default settings) takes about 1-7 seconds for a checkpoint size of 80 Mb.

Comment: Is it about batch processing or batch processing in Spark?

Comment: @thebluephantom batch processing in general

Comment: Ok, but it seems spark related.

Comment: @thebluephantom I don't care if you answer in the context of flink. I just wanted a general opinion from everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked some colleagues, got these examples:

1. Postgres connector, for example, doesn't support `sparkSession.readStream` only `sparkSession.read`
2. You can't do window functions with microbatches properly, for example, if a window function needs to be applied to the whole dataset, you can't do that with streaming, or if you can, it is extremely hard. Although if your version of Spar supports MERGE INTO, it can be done in some way.

I'm sure there are other things as well, hope somebody posts a more comprehensive list.

Answer (score 0):

Batch processing is not going away. They should be the first choice for offline processing of large data.

I have worked on both Apache Spark and Apache Flink apps. Both can be suboptimal for the use case at hand.

I will give you two imaginary examples For a high traffic travel website (note: this is purely imaginary and details have been changed. I haven't worked in this domain.) and explain why streaming is better for one and batching for the other.

Use case 1: Build a user profile of each user based on their activity online. For each user we want to build a profile of their behavior - how long user browses a page, what is user's frequency of visits to the website, user's geographic area of search, products searched etc. This will be built everyday as an aggregate of last 30 days. Originally this was built with Flink which read a Kinesis stream of page activity and output the User profile every hour to a NoSQL DB. Travel websites typicaly have 10 million active users in a year. This caused the checkpoint size to be huge during peak usage times causing frequent maintenance issues. Exporting the user activity and User Ids to Amazon S3  and running a Spark Job to join the two datasets is a far easier and manageable solution.

Use case 2: Monitor the user's online activity to identify possible scrapping attempts. This involves maintaining a count of the number of pages a user has accessed in the last 1 minute. In this case the processing interval is 1 minute, the state associated with each user is very small. A Flink app that monitors user activity on a stream is well suited for this. It may be a good choice for Spark Streaming, but this is not a batch processing use case.

As you can see, Batch systems should be the first choice for large data processing tasks that can be done offline.